# Using Configuration Manager.GetSection with Configuration Manager.OpenExe

Tags: c#, configuration, mef

I have an executable that consumes DLL’s through MEF. I am successfully loading each DLL’s config file's appsettings keys using

```
    var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        return appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["Version"].Value;
```

Now I want to make it so the DLL allows for adhoc items in the DLL’s config file.

So I added this to the config file

```
    <configSections>
            <section name="AdHocRules" type="BusinessRules.AdHocConfiguration, BusinessRules" />
    </configSections>   
                <AdHocRules BaseRuleNumber="ConfigEx1" RuleName="Config Example" EffectiveDate="5/1/2010" Value="Example" IsValid="true"/>
```

And I created a class to read the above. And when I run this in a test console app that is not consuming the DLL – so everything is complied together and a single app config everything works fine

BUT – I want to use the DLL’s config file and I keep getting an error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Configuration.DefaultSection'
>   to type
>   'BusinessRules.AdHocConfiguration

This is not working; - it's throwing the above

```
var cm = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
AdHocConfiguration adhoc = (AdHocConfiguration)cm.GetSection("AdHocRules");
```

And this is code – adhoc is null because it is not loading from the correct config file

```
    AdHocConfiguration adhoc = (AdHocConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("AdHocRules");


            BusinessRules.Rule r = new BusinessRules.Rule();
            r.BaseRuleNumber = adhoc.baserulenumber;
            r.RuleName = adhoc.rulename;
            r.EffectiveDate = adhoc.effectivedate;
            r.Value = adhoc.value;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the OpenExeConfiguration method, the configuration files for the other DLLs need to reside in the same directory as the executable file as they mention in the [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx).

You might need a post-build event to move the config files, but it does work.

Also you might want to use Assembly.GetAssembly(***some type loaded by MEF***).Location; rather than Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, depending on how you are using it.

I have a sample project where I load parts using MEF, and read their config files.

Let me know if you still have trouble